# Match query which matches exactly to a field with shuffling

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field in `Elasticsearch` which has array of string. This field has standard analyzer.

```
e.g

Document 1
{ field:["a b c d", "a b c x", "b a c y"]}

Document 2
{ field:["a b c"]}
```

Now I am searching "b c a" using match query with 100% match.
I am getting both the documents which is correct.
But I want only Document 2.
How can I get only Document2 using match query?

Comment: Can you post the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I am using data type called [token_count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/token-count.html)
It will calculate and store the count of tokens for each text.
This count value can be utilized to get the documents with exact number of tokens as searched text

```
PUT testindex6
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "search_text": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "text": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "length": {
                "type": "token_count",
                "analyzer": "standard"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "testindex6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Il1fDm0B27hOMovb2NOC",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "search_text" : [
            {
              "text" : "a b c d"
            },
            {
              "text" : "a b c d e"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "I11fDm0B27hOMovb99NK",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "search_text" : [
            {
              "text" : "a b c"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
GET testindex6/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "search_text",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "search_text.text": "b c a"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "search_text.text.length": {
                  "value": 3   ----> pass the number of tokens searched for 
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, token_count datatype internally calculates the string length but for that i have to wrap string in an object. I mean i have to convert array of string to array of wrapped object in index.

Comment: yes, each string has to be an object(not necessarily a nested field) for this to work